# Antivirus Scan on an uploaded file stream Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, antivirus, antivirus-integration

I am looking for an antivirus scan for scanning the filestream that is uploaded from a rest api using express.

Found clamscan as one option but it has some linux dependencies.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/clamscan

Is there a better way to do an anti virus scan on a filestream in nodejs

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use a SaaS product, check out [www.scanii.com](https://www.scanii.com), it allows you to move the scanning to the client's browser so those files never reach your sever: https://docs.scanii.com/article/153-client-side-content-arbitration-with-scanii

Full disclosure: I work on scanii